# Access to RStudio Server hosted on EC2 through Django App on S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a R Shiny app running on a EC2 instance on AWS. The app can be accessed directly through its link.

I also have a Django app hosted on S3, which is accessing the app as an iframe.

What I want to do is limit the access of the Shiny App only through the Django app. Currently there is no limit on the EC2 instance security groups, and they listen ports 80 & 22.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Are you sure your Django app is running on S3? S3 can only host static websites...

Comment: My bad. Its still being developed locally, but I plan on deploying it on AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like the answer to be simple and say you just need to restrict the access to your Shiny app to the IP of your Django App but unfortunately you are using iframes.

As you are using an iframe, the content of that iframe needs to be accessible to whoever is accessing your Django app. If your Django app needs to be accessible from anywhere, the content of your iframe needs to be accessible from anywhere.

You can mitigate the access to the content of your Shiny app though. You can use the [X-Frame-Options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking#X-Frame-Options) header to prevent your Shiny app from being embedded on other websites. You can set up nginx for example to serve your Shiny app and set these headers.

Here are some useful links:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67889/why-do-browsers-enforce-the-same-origin-security-policy-on-iframes (about X-Frame-Options)

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65619/protect-a-url-from-being-used-in-an-iframe-except-on-a-single-site (about Referer)

[How to get parent URL in a shiny-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985959/how-to-get-parent-url-in-a-shiny-app) (same issue as you)